# Topology of Manifolds and Kunneth fomula by Griffiths Harris

Tags: algebraic-topology, compact-manifolds, complex-manifolds

Reading Griffiths-Harris, at page 56 I find some parts that I can't understand.

1) After having proved the Poincaré Duality Theorem, Griffiths and Harris proceed to prove a weaker result, that's to say

$P: H_k(M,\mathbb{Q}) \mapsto H_{n-k}(M,\mathbb{Q})^{*}$ given by $P(A)(B)=(A.B)$ is the intersection pairing.

Why are considering the case of the homology group with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$ when the duality theorem is stated for homologies with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$?

They do the same thing below when they talk about the Kunneth formula. How can they pass from coefficients of a type to coefficients of another type so freely?

2) They also say that via the De Rham isomorphism $H_{DR}^{n-k} \mapsto H^{n-k}(M,\mathbb{C})$, this is equivalent to the assertion that for any $n-k$ cycle $B$ su $M$ holds the relation $\int_B \phi=(A.B)$, and this is ok! At the end of the proof they define the bilinear map  $H_{DR}^k(M) \otimes H_{DR}^{n-k}(M) \mapsto H_{DR}^n(M) \simeq \mathbb{C}$. Is it always true that if $M$ is a complex compact $n-$dimensional manifold, it's $n^{th}$-cohomology group is always isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$?

Can you explain me this points, please?

Comment: It is true that the top cohomology of a compact connected complex manifold is $\mathbb{C}$; it is a general result that a compact connected oriented manifold has top cohomology 1 dimensional.

Comment: Can you suggest me a reference with a proof of this fact? Or can you answer giving a proof, please?

Comment: Oh, yeah, using Poincaré Duality, this is $H_0(M)$, which is $1-$dimensional because the compact manifold is connected.

Comment: I've been told that you shouldn't learn this topological material from Griffiths-Harris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that an isomorphism $H_k\to H_{n-k}^*$ is very different than an isomorphism $H_k\to H^{n-k}$! A cohomology class determines an element of $H_{n-k}^*$, but the converse does not hold over $\mathbb{Z}$. Instead, $H^{n-k}(M,\mathbb{Z})\cong H_{n-k}(M,\mathbb{Z})^*\oplus \mathrm{Tors}(H_{n-k-1})(M,\mathbb{Z})$. Intuitively, taking $\mathbb{Q}$ coefficients instead of $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients kills torsion but preserves the free part (one proof is by the universal coefficient theorem,) so that Poincaré duality implies $H_k(M,\mathbb{Q})\cong H_{n-k}(M,\mathbb{Q})$. Then Griffiths-Harris' proposition is just making that isomorphism explicit.

Comment: The same fact happens with Kunneth formula?

Comment: Which fact, exactly? You didn't indicate quite what GH claim about Künneth.

Comment: They construct an isomorphism (modulo torsion) $H_{*}(M,\mathbb{Z}) \otimes H_{*}(N,\mathbb{Z}) \mapsto H_{*}(M \times N, \mathbb{Z})$ and at page 58, they say "we have established the Kunneth formula $H_{*}(M,\mathbb{Q}) \otimes H_{*}(N,\mathbb{Q}) \mapsto H_{*}(M \times N, \mathbb{Q})$".

Comment: Right, that's true for the same reason.